# MariaDB TX (Enterprise) vs free differences?

Tags: encryption, mariadb, audit, privacy

[MariaDB TX](https://mariadb.com/products/solutions/oltp-database-tx) is the name of MariaDB's enterprise version and is comparable to MySQL Enterprise, and it seems to be a rather new product, as it's not mentioned at all on the [MariaDB wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MariaDB).

They seem to have a focus on [GDPR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Data_Protection_Regulation) and personal privacy, with features such as database encryption, auditing, data protection, threat detection/prevention.

But what I can't figure out is what do I get from using the free version of MariaDB and what features are missing out, that are important from the aspects of GDPR.

What are the differences between the two, and is the free edition good enough to increase the security, perhaps by add some other free external applications to do auditing and threat detection?

Answer (score 0):

If you need GDPR, you need help; it would be folly to try to do it with any free product.

If you are storing sensitive information, you need help.  I cringe when anyone asks for free help on this site, and mentions the existence of SSNs, Credit Card numbers, etc.  It is much easier to get free hacking tools than free protection tools.

Other than that, there is a lot that *can* be done with MariaDB and MySQL.  The free versions are fine for individuals and small companies (except for sensitive info).  Most of the major web sites are powered by some version  of MySQL.

Since you have not spelled out what your app will do, I can't be more specific.

Comment: Thanks, I think I’ll delete this question and rephrase it to ”can mariadb do X”. I dont store ssn or cc by the way, but even name and email are considered personal data and encryption at rest is recommended

Comment: OK.  Hopefully someone else can help you.  Encryption-at-rest is one area where MySQL 8.0 and MariaDB are battling for supremacy.  (I don't know the details.)

Comment: You seem to mean 'non-free help' when mentioning 'help' in this answer!? Probably you mean 'professional help'. And then again: that could be said for every issue on this site.

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB TX is a solution, not a single piece of software. It is a collection of software and tools that provides [a complete database solution](https://mariadb.com/products/solutions/oltp-database-tx) [sic] and one of those is the MariaDB Server. They use the same packages and source code as the "free" MariaDB version (all versions of MariaDB are free) so it has the same features.

A good, practical view of the software in MariaDB TX can be seen on the [TX Downloads](https://mariadb.com/downloads/mariadb-tx) page. You see the MariaDB server, [MaxScale](https://mariadb.com/products/technology/maxscale), connectors and tools.